# fullpage.js - Jump to specific section from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Is there any way to jump directly to a specific section from an external link? At present I have a link with the anchor but fullpage.js loads the page and then scrolls to the anchor. I would like to jump "directly" to the specified anchor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plugin option `animateAnchor:false` which you can find [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options).

> **animateAnchor:** (default true) Defines whether the load of the site when given an anchor (#) will scroll with animation to its destination or will directly load on **the given section**.

Take into account that this only jumps directly to the section. In case you have an anchor with a section and and slide, the section will load directly and the slide will be reached after the automatic slide to it.

Example of usage:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors:['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
    animateAnchor: false
});
```